# Instagram API - Missing values from request /tags/xxx/media/recent

Tags: api, instagram

This is very strange. The request to /tags/chiara8anos/media/recent is working fine.

The problem is that the profile is public (http://instagram.com/chiaratroccoli) and i can fetch all images except this http://instagram.com/p/fYtRx0Qvit/.

The API is not returning this specific post but the hashtag, #chiara8anos, is correctly there as you can see. So the request /tags/chiara8anos/media/recent should have this.

I noticed that the image is not on amazon bucket as is use to be. This specific image is here: http://distilleryimage9.ak.instagram.com/4852dfbc339711e3817122000ab5bea8_8.jpg

If you try to use api-console (http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/)  with this request https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/chiara8anos/media/recent you won't be able to fetch this post even paginating.

Is it a bug? Some limitation from Instagram?

Comment: I can't explain why it is not showing up in the api search, but I am seeing a lot of pictures being served from distilleryimagex.ak.instagram.com.

Comment: Also this picture is not being displayed from the hashtag search using the Instagram app, so it is not just the public API.

Comment: the images you are seeing coming from ak.instagram.com are from profile_picture, right? (e.g - "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg") i'm talking about the standard_resolution image (e.g - "standard_resolution": {"url": "http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/d6d33a9e33a511e3aba922000ab5ba87_8.jpg")

Comment: No, I am talking about the 612x612 resolution media images. Many of them are from distilleryimage.ak.instagram.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the /users endpoint, that image is returned correctly and has standard_resolution: http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/4852dfbc339711e3817122000ab5bea8_8.jpg

which is the usual AmazonAWS URL This is the endpoint: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/605729285/media/recent?access_token=

But you are right saying that the image is not returned using the /tags endpoint. It looks like an Instagram bug to me.

Comment: Yes, using the /users endpoint i see the image there. that's why when accessing the user's profile i can see it (http://instagram.com/p/fYtRx0Qvit/). I think its a bug. I also opened a thread on instagram-api-developers but nobody replied.

Comment: I'm suffering the same problem. Tried to reach Instagram but no response either. This search https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/glamboxcat/ does not return both this https://www.instagram.com/p/BB5lq6RwRt9/ and this , and so does not the API.